# Structured and sorted table with CTE Query with a parent and predecessor column

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a MS SQL table/data like this

| id | parent_id | predecessor_id | title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 268437302 | NULL | 0 | 0P |
| 268437303 | 268437302 | 0 | 0P.00 |
| 268437304 | 268437302 | 268437303 | 0P.01 |
| 268437305 | 268437302 | 268437304 | 0P.02 |
| 268437307 | 268437306 | 0 | 0P.03.AK |
| 268437308 | 268437306 | 268437307 | 0P.03.00 |
| 268437309 | 268437306 | 268437308 | 0P.03.BBK |
| 268437316 | 268437302 | 268437306 | 0P.04 |
| 268437317 | 268437316 | 0 | 0P.04.01 |
| 268437318 | 268437317 | 0 | 0P.04.01.Andi |
| 268437319 | 268437317 | 268437318 | 0P.04.01.Marc |
| 268437320 | 268437317 | 268437319 | 0P.04.01.Peter |
| 268437321 | 268437317 | 268437320 | 0P.04.01.Charlie |
| 268437322 | 268437317 | 268437321 | 0P.04.01.Gaby |
| 268437339 | 268437302 | 268437316 | 0P.99 |
| 268437340 | NULL | 268437302 | 0B |
| 268437341 | 268437340 | 0 | 0B.01 |
| 268437342 | 268437341 | 0 | 0B.01.Thomas |
| 268437343 | 268437341 | 268437342 | 0B.01.Nico |
| 268437344 | 268437341 | 268437343 | 0B.01.Daniel |
| 268437345 | 268437341 | 268437344 | 0B.01.Manuel |
| 268437365 | NULL | 268437340 | 0C |
| 268437366 | 268437365 | 0 | 0C.AB |

I need a structured and sorted table.
Now I can make a recursive CTE and receive almost the correct result.

```
;WITH cte AS
(SELECT *, 1 AS Level
FROM struct_table
WHERE parent_id = '268435455'
UNION ALL
SELECT QRY.*, Level+1
FROM struct_table AS QRY
INNER JOIN
cte ON cte.id = QRY.parent_id)
SELECT 
AKTENPLANZEICHEN,
CASE WHEN Level = 1 THEN [title] ELSE '' END AS LEVEL1,
CASE WHEN Level = 2 THEN [title] ELSE '' END AS LEVEL2,
CASE WHEN Level = 3 THEN [title] ELSE '' END AS LEVEL3,
CASE WHEN Level = 4 THEN [title] ELSE '' END AS LEVEL4,
CASE WHEN Level = 5 THEN [title] ELSE '' END AS LEVEL5,
id,
parent_id,
predecessor_id
FROM cte
ORDER BY title
```

| LEVEL1 | LEVEL2 | LEVEL3 | LEVEL4 | LEVEL5 | id | parent_id | predecessor_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0P |  |  |  |  | 268437302 | NULL | 0 |
|  | 0P.00 |  |  |  | 268437303 | 268437302 | 0 |
|  | 0P.01 |  |  |  | 268437304 | 268437302 | 268437303 |
|  | 0P.02 |  |  |  | 268437305 | 268437302 | 268437304 |
|  | 0P.03 |  |  |  | 268437306 | 268437302 | 268437305 |
|  |  | 0P.03.00 |  |  | 268437308 | 268437306 | 268437307 |
|  |  | 0P.03.AK |  |  | 268437307 | 268437306 | 0 |
|  |  | 0P.03.BBK |  |  | 268437309 | 268437306 | 268437308 |
|  | 0P.04 |  |  |  | 268437316 | 268437302 | 268437306 |
|  |  | 0P.04.01 |  |  | 268437317 | 268437316 | 0 |
|  |  |  | 0P.04.01.Andi |  | 268437318 | 268437317 | 0 |
|  |  |  | 0P.04.01.Charlie |  | 268437321 | 268437317 | 268437320 |
|  |  |  | 0P.04.01.Gaby |  | 268437322 | 268437317 | 268437321 |
|  |  |  | 0P.04.01.Marc |  | 268437319 | 268437317 | 268437318 |
|  |  |  | 0P.04.01.Peter |  | 268437320 | 268437317 | 268437319 |
|  | 0P.99 |  |  |  | 268437339 | 268437302 | 268437316 |
| 0B |  |  |  |  | 268437340 | NULL | 268437302 |
|  | 0B.01 |  |  |  | 268437341 | 268437340 | 0 |
|  |  | 0B.01.Daniel |  |  | 268437344 | 268437341 | 268437343 |
|  |  | 0B.01.Manuel |  |  | 268437345 | 268437341 | 268437344 |
|  |  | 0B.01.Nico |  |  | 268437343 | 268437341 | 268437342 |
|  |  | 0B.01.Thomas |  |  | 268437342 | 268437341 | 0 |
| 0C |  |  |  |  | 268437365 | NULL | 268437340 |
|  | 0C.AB |  |  |  | 268437366 | 268437365 | 0 |

BUT with this statement **the column predecessor_id ist ignored** and the order is not correct e.g. the 0P.04.01.Charlie should be after 0P.04.01.Peter etc.

Is there a solutions for my problem?

Comment: 0P.03 is missing in struct_table. Will you please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes your desired query:

```
with cte as (
select id root_id,id,parent_id,predecessor_id,title,1 level from struct_table where parent_id is null
union all 
select root_id root_id, struct_table.*,level+1 level from struct_table inner join cte on struct_table.parent_id =cte.id 
)
select 

CASE WHEN Level = 1 THEN [title] ELSE '' END AS LEVEL1,
CASE WHEN Level = 2 THEN [title] ELSE '' END AS LEVEL2,
CASE WHEN Level = 3 THEN [title] ELSE '' END AS LEVEL3,
CASE WHEN Level = 4 THEN [title] ELSE '' END AS LEVEL4,
CASE WHEN Level = 5 THEN [title] ELSE '' END AS LEVEL5,
root_id,id,parent_id,predecessor_id,title,level from cte
order by root_id,parent_id,predecessor_id
```

DB-Fiddle Link:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a40cff1016abcf13c98a4146a2e660fb

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But with this query I still have exactly the same problem - the order is not correct.

e.g. correct is 1) 0B.01.Thomas | 268437342 | 268437341 | 0 // 2) 0B.01.Nico | 268437343 | 268437341 | 268437342 // 3) 0B.01.Daniel | 268437344 | 268437341 | 268437343 // 4) 0B.01.Manuel | 268437345 | 268437341 | 268437344

Comment: @KMen I have changed my answer. Now the order is as you want.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> create table struct_table (id varchar(25),parent_id varchar(25),predecessor_id varchar(25),title varchar(25));
> insert into struct_table values('268437302',NULL,'0','0P');
> insert into struct_table values('268437303','268437302','0','0P.00');
> insert into struct_table values('268437304','268437302','268437303','0P.01');
> insert into struct_table values('268437305','268437302','268437304','0P.02');
> insert into struct_table values('268437306','268437302','268437305','0P.03');
> insert into struct_table values('268437307','268437306','0','0P.03.AK');
> insert into struct_table values('268437308','268437306','268437307','0P.03.00');
> insert into struct_table values('268437309','268437306','268437308','0P.03.BBK');
> insert into struct_table values('268437316','268437302','268437306','0P.04');
> insert into struct_table values('268437317','268437316','0','0P.04.01');
> insert into struct_table values('268437318','268437317','0','0P.04.01.Andi');
> insert into struct_table values('268437319','268437317','268437318','0P.04.01.Marc');
> insert into struct_table values('268437320','268437317','268437319','0P.04.01.Peter');
> insert into struct_table values('268437321','268437317','268437320','0P.04.01.Charlie');
> insert into struct_table values('268437322','268437317','268437321','0P.04.01.Gaby');
> insert into struct_table values('268437339','268437302','268437316','0P.99');
> insert into struct_table values('268437340',NULL,'268437302','0B');
> insert into struct_table values('268437341','268437340','0','0B.01');
> insert into struct_table values('268437342','268437341','0','0B.01.Thomas');
> insert into struct_table values('268437343','268437341','268437342','0B.01.Nico');
> insert into struct_table values('268437344','268437341','268437343','0B.01.Daniel');
> insert into struct_table values('268437345','268437341','268437344','0B.01.Manuel');
> insert into struct_table values('268437365',NULL,'268437340','0C');
> insert into struct_table values('268437366','268437365','0','0C.AB');
>
>
> with cte as (
> select id root_id,id,parent_id,predecessor_id,title,1 level from struct_table where parent_id is null
> union all 
> select root_id root_id, struct_table.*,level+1 level from struct_table inner join cte on struct_table.parent_id =cte.id 
> )
> select 
>
> CASE WHEN Level = 1 THEN [title] ELSE '' END AS LEVEL1,
> CASE WHEN Level = 2 THEN [title] ELSE '' END AS LEVEL2,
> CASE WHEN Level = 3 THEN [title] ELSE '' END AS LEVEL3,
> CASE WHEN Level = 4 THEN [title] ELSE '' END AS LEVEL4,
> CASE WHEN Level = 5 THEN [title] ELSE '' END AS LEVEL5,
> root_id,id,parent_id,predecessor_id,title,level from cte
> order by root_id,parent_id,predecessor_id
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> LEVEL1 | LEVEL2 | LEVEL3       | LEVEL4           | LEVEL5 | root_id   | id        | parent_id | predecessor_id | title            | level
> :----- | :----- | :----------- | :--------------- | :----- | :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :------------- | :--------------- | ----:
> 0P     |        |              |                  |        | 268437302 | 268437302 | null      | 0              | 0P               |     1
>        | 0P.00  |              |                  |        | 268437302 | 268437303 | 268437302 | 0              | 0P.00            |     2
>        | 0P.01  |              |                  |        | 268437302 | 268437304 | 268437302 | 268437303      | 0P.01            |     2
>        | 0P.02  |              |                  |        | 268437302 | 268437305 | 268437302 | 268437304      | 0P.02            |     2
>        | 0P.03  |              |                  |        | 268437302 | 268437306 | 268437302 | 268437305      | 0P.03            |     2
>        | 0P.04  |              |                  |        | 268437302 | 268437316 | 268437302 | 268437306      | 0P.04            |     2
>        | 0P.99  |              |                  |        | 268437302 | 268437339 | 268437302 | 268437316      | 0P.99            |     2
>        |        | 0P.03.AK     |                  |        | 268437302 | 268437307 | 268437306 | 0              | 0P.03.AK         |     3
>        |        | 0P.03.00     |                  |        | 268437302 | 268437308 | 268437306 | 268437307      | 0P.03.00         |     3
>        |        | 0P.03.BBK    |                  |        | 268437302 | 268437309 | 268437306 | 268437308      | 0P.03.BBK        |     3
>        |        | 0P.04.01     |                  |        | 268437302 | 268437317 | 268437316 | 0              | 0P.04.01         |     3
>        |        |              | 0P.04.01.Andi    |        | 268437302 | 268437318 | 268437317 | 0              | 0P.04.01.Andi    |     4
>        |        |              | 0P.04.01.Marc    |        | 268437302 | 268437319 | 268437317 | 268437318      | 0P.04.01.Marc    |     4
>        |        |              | 0P.04.01.Peter   |        | 268437302 | 268437320 | 268437317 | 268437319      | 0P.04.01.Peter   |     4
>        |        |              | 0P.04.01.Charlie |        | 268437302 | 268437321 | 268437317 | 268437320      | 0P.04.01.Charlie |     4
>        |        |              | 0P.04.01.Gaby    |        | 268437302 | 268437322 | 268437317 | 268437321      | 0P.04.01.Gaby    |     4
> 0B     |        |              |                  |        | 268437340 | 268437340 | null      | 268437302      | 0B               |     1
>        | 0B.01  |              |                  |        | 268437340 | 268437341 | 268437340 | 0              | 0B.01            |     2
>        |        | 0B.01.Thomas |                  |        | 268437340 | 268437342 | 268437341 | 0              | 0B.01.Thomas     |     3
>        |        | 0B.01.Nico   |                  |        | 268437340 | 268437343 | 268437341 | 268437342      | 0B.01.Nico       |     3
>        |        | 0B.01.Daniel |                  |        | 268437340 | 268437344 | 268437341 | 268437343      | 0B.01.Daniel     |     3
>        |        | 0B.01.Manuel |                  |        | 268437340 | 268437345 | 268437341 | 268437344      | 0B.01.Manuel     |     3
> 0C     |        |              |                  |        | 268437365 | 268437365 | null      | 268437340      | 0C               |     1
>        | 0C.AB  |              |                  |        | 268437365 | 268437366 | 268437365 | 0              | 0C.AB            |     2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=af6d0cf734bb720a52bac3094c792e94)*

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for the quick reply.
I have also think about this solution. However, this only works if the IDs have a defined row sequence. But this is exactly not the case.

E.G.
| id | parent_id | predecessor_id | title |
| -------- | -------------- | -------------- | -------------- |
| 268437342 | 268437341 | 0  | 0B.01.Thomas
| 268437345 | 268437341 | 268437342 | 0B.01.Manuel
| 268437343 | 268437341 | 268437345 | 0B.01.Nico
| 268437344 | 268437341 | 268437343 | 0B.01.Daniel
| 268437345 | 268437341 | 268437344 | 0B.01.Manuel